# Can I embed Skype Chat into my website

Tags: skype

I'd like to embed a skype chat box into my website. Is that possible? I'm running a LAMP architecture but am open to using a different vps if needed

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have you tried `<a href="skype:-skype-name-?chat">Start chat</a>` ?

Comment: Not exactly what I was after but this is the best solution available at this stage.

Comment: Is it possible to integrate skype's video calling functionality?

Answer (score 10):

**UPDATED 2019-11-23**

**Skype Webcontrol** has been removed from the Microsoft platform. Could be related to the release of **Skype for Web**.

In this moment it's strongly recommended to use an alternative solution like [Facebook Web Messenger](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/) for your site.

---

**UPDATED 2018-09-05** *(This information is not valid anymore)*

Yes, now it's possible on the following link [Skype Webcontrol](https://dev.skype.com/webcontrol)

The HTML code to add a call button is:

```
<span class="skype-button rounded" data-contact-id="skype-user-name"></span>
<script src="https://swc.cdn.skype.com/sdk/v1/sdk.min.js"></script>
```

Set the "*skype-user-name*" and voilá... nothing else is required.

---

**OLD POST:**

No, you cannot embed Skype chat in your website by the time this post is done.
But these are some resources that might be useful:

This is the official site for creating a Skype button in your website for **chat** or **call**:
https://www.skype.com/en/developer/create-contactme-buttons/

But I will have to advise that your visitors require Skype Software installed and it's correspondent extension installed. On mobile browsers it will require only the Skype App installed.

This is the HTML code for the website:

**SKYPE CALL**

```
<a href="skype:USERNAME?call">call using Skype</a>
```

**SKYPE CHAT**

```
<a href="skype:USERNAME?chat">Chat with Skype</a>
```

**SKYPE VOICEMAIL**

```
<a href="skype:USERNAME?voicemail">Leave a voicemail</a>
```

Source: http://www.vividstar.co.uk/2012/09/embedding-skype-html-on-your-website/

Skype URI API for the Web: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn745883.aspx

Skype API: https://www.skype.com/en/developer/

Comment: Is it possible to integrate skype's video calling functionality?

Comment: No, you still can't. Time goes on and Skype it's still a VERY closed platform.

Comment: https://dev.skype.com/webcontrol just takes me to the Skype home page.  Has the url changed?

Comment: Webcontrol is not available anymore. The JS files are getting removed from the CDNs. Seems bad news for these Skype features. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/all/skype-web-control-not-working/836cec51-030b-408d-8183-85b716c1a05b

Answer (score 2):

Someone may found this helpful.

```
<span class="skype-button bubble " data-contact-id="your-skype-id"></span>
<script src="https://swc.cdn.skype.com/sdk/v1/sdk.min.js"></script>
```

found [here](https://dev.skype.com/webcontrol)..

Answer (score 1):

It is only possible to start the locally installed Skype-client on the visitors computer from your website.

Skype provides an api for this:

http://dev.skype.com/skype-uri

And here you'll find a Skype URI Tutorial:

http://dev.skype.com/skype-uri/skype-uri-tutorial-webpages

What you're looking for is a live support chat. There are plenty commercial offerings out there. Maybe you can also find some [free script](https://www.google.com/search?q=live%20support%20chat%20server).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this using Skype Web SDK.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn962133(v=office.16).aspx

Comment: Note that this is only for paid skype.

Answer (score 1):

These answers are old and not relevant at the moment. Using the unofficial NodeJS API for skype, one can embed the newer cloud based chat groups.

https://github.com/ShyykoSerhiy/skyweb (I am in no way associated with this project)

```
var skyweb = new Skyweb();
skyweb.login(username, password).then((skypeAccount) => {
    skyweb.createThread([{"id":"8:someuserid","role":"User"},
    {"id":"8:live:someliveuserid","role":"User"}
    {"id":"8:youruserid","role":"Admin"}]);
});
```